# emacs local version control

Tags: version-control, emacs, local, snapshot

I am wondering if there is local version control/snapshots for emacs independent of VC?
let me clarify:
every time I save buffer, I would like to be able to keep track of changes of each save in session.  I know I can do something similar with backup files, but they are not automated like VC and a somewhat cumbersome.

I have searched Google, but did not find the solution.
Perhaps my query string was not good.

I found this for eclipse, am looking for emacs equivalent:
http://help.eclipse.org/help32/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/gettingStarted/qs-55.htm

Thanks

Comment: What features do you want that backup files don't give you?  See the `version-control` variable, or this page here http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/?id=BackupDirectory for more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK there is no such solution, but you can make some ad hoc one - like creating a local VCS repository and advice the save-buffer command to commit the changes in the repository.

I also came across a [section of the manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Local-Version-Control.html) that might be of interest to you.

Comment: okay, I think I can automate the stuff from the manual.  kazakstan?

Comment: I'd use a hook, rather than advice; but otherwise: yeah, what Bozhidar said.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a way to get Emacs to save buffer snapshots, but keep in mind that it has an infinite undo facility. If you just want a way to get back to earlier versions, that might help you. If you want real version control, then I'd go with Bozhidar Batsov's solution and advice the save-buffer command.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BackupEachSave

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.